# Why doesn't R' Yehuda believe the Eidim Zomemim after the first set?

Tags: edim-witnesses

As I already [asked in this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/103358/501), based on the Mishna in [Makkos 1:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Makkot.1.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), that Rabbi Yehuda says that only the first set of  Eidim Zomemim are put to death.

If the same 2 witnesses disqualify further sets of witnesses by saying "but you were with us - far away - when the crime happened" they are not put to death.

In the original:

> בָּאוּ אֲחֵרִים וְהִזִּימוּם, בָּאוּ אֲחֵרִים וְהִזִּימוּם, אֲפִלּוּ מֵאָה, כֻּלָּם יֵהָרֵגוּ. 
>   **רַבִּי יְהוּדָה אוֹמֵר, אִסְטָסִית הִיא זוֹ, וְאֵינָהּ נֶהֱרֶגֶת אֶלָּא כַת הָרִאשׁוֹנָה בִלְבָד**
>   :‏
>
> If other witnesses came, and they charged them [with perjury]: then [again] others came, and they [again] charged them [with perjury], even a hundred, they are all to be executed. **Rabbi Judah says: “This is a conspiracy and the first set alone is [to be] executed.”**

What puzzles me is why Rabbi Yehuda is worried that it's a conspiracy.

Surely the *disqualifying witnesses* aren't believed without being cross-examined.

If they get through the rather grueling cross-examination needed in capital offenses - as described in the 5th chapter of Sanhedrin - then why aren't they believed for subsequent sets of witnesses?

Is this some type of Gezarat HaKatuv (i.e. does Rabbi Yehuda have a Pasuk or Mesora for this)? Or are these *disqualifying witnesses* not cross-examined? (Since the cross-examination is not mentioned anywhere.)

I can't find anybody who discusses this.

Comment: Maybe that’s why the Halacha is does not follow him.

Comment: @DrShmuel He thought the halakha does follow him. Why?

Comment: Maybe they just have a really elaborate scheme which R Yehuda is concerned about.

Comment: "the rather grueling cross-examination needed in capital offenses" - the required basic cross-examination is not terribly grueling, and it would be the exact questions they already answered regarding the first set, which they already answered successfully. Further cross-examination is at the court's prerogative.